# Phabricator arc diff message to reviewers

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

With Phabricator's Arcanist is there a way when you run `arc diff` and edit the commit message to include a message to reviewers that doesn't end up in the commit message. Something like:

```
Add some comments

Summary: Adds comments to libfoo and libbar explaining foo() and bar().

Test Plan: No.

Reviewers: dave, john

Subscribers:

Review Message: These are just some comments I had lying around - please check them for technical correctness thanks!
```

Obviously I don't want the `Review Message:` to show up in git.